# Pandas: convert series of time YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.0 keeping the YYYY-MM-DD format only

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Pandas: convert series of time YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.0 keeping the YYYY-MM-DD format only

python 3.6, pandas 0.19.0

```
     timestamp
0    2013-01-14 21:19:42.0
1    2013-01-16 09:04:37.0
2    2013-03-20 12:50:49.0
3    2013-01-03 17:02:53.0
4    2013-04-13 16:44:20.0
```

I tried:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

`AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.`
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: You have to use `df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the series into datetime datatype and try,

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

it may satisfy your demand

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the below shown method also helps to achieve the same.

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.date

You can refer to the documentation provided in the below link as a handy guide for date time handling:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties